# Include statement in pug/jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I want to use a variable provided from my CMS to reference an include template like this:

```
extends layout
    include layouts/#{data[0].fields.layout}.pug
```

This just looks for `layouts/#{data[0].fields.layout}.pug` rather than what I wan, e.g. `main.pug`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use a variable in a Jade include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132978/use-a-variable-in-a-jade-include)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible at the moment. Dynamic includes are currently not supported by Pug (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42774876) and [this Github issue](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/1955)).